# A Java Development Kit must be available in order to run Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I was able to run Eclipse until I tried to install another compiler, suggested by a online tutorial for C++. Now I'm getting the 'No virtual machine was found error'. I know I'm suppose to match the versions of the programs but I can't seem to figure it out. I thought I had downloaded 64 bit version of each program in Eclipse and JDK but I don't know how to verify it. I go to each file and try to get the info but I must be looking in the wrong places. I have copied the file location of JDK and pasted it in the Advanced System Settings in Environment Variables. In the Systems Variables for User on the variable line I typed "path", on the value line I pasted the location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin. I have even uninstalled both programs several times and reinstalled them. I've been at it for several hours now with no success. Any suggestions, anybody. Thank you.

Comment: open your `eclipse.ini` and follow this http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example . By the way using Eclipse for C/C++ is a terrible idea, it's an horrible IDE on its own, but for stuff like C/C++ it should really be the last choice. QtCreator is way simpler and better suited for C/C++ programming.

Comment: I can't open eclipse, that's why I posted the question. But I'm going to look at Qt to see if it's a better compiler for C++ programming. Thanks for answering, though.

Comment: I want to get this right so that I don't screw up my computer. Are you suggesting that I insert this path -vm
C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe  in the Environment Variables where the variable and value lines are? Meaning that instead of path on the top line I type '-vm' and put the JDK location on the bottom line?

Comment: yes, you need to input the full path to your `javaw` executable available on your machine, be sure that it's executable, you are just editing a config file, you are not screwing up anything if you do the right thing.